# Rendering from at batch file fails on Windows

Tags: rendering

It's my first time trying to use a batch file so I can render lots of files over night but cant get it to work. Looked up several tutorials and none seem to work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Also, the file location is on the One-Drive cloud folder, should this make a difference?

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
blender -b "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Buildings\Malvern\Sienna\Pavilion\8x8\layout_A" -a
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the file extension. The full name of the file is "layout_A.blend". So your command should be:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
blender -b "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Buildings\Malvern\Sienna\Pavilion\8x8\layout_A.blend" -a
```

Comment: many thanks! this fixed it